# first click change to new image and second click change to old image, android

Tags: android

this application requires:
first click will change image1 to image2
second click will change back to old image (image2 to image1)

```
image1  = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        image1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.a3_01);
                image1.setTag(70);              
            }
        });
```

this image will set a new tag for the server knows that the picture have been change.

*the code i used is only for the first click and it works. ive just have no idea to make a second click event. can anyone gives me idea of it? much appreciate. thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use a boolean to act as a switch for you to flop back and forth with an if statement.

```
boolean showingFirst = true;
image1  = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
image1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(showingFirst == true){
            image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.a3_02);
            showingFirst = false;
        }else{
            image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.a3_01);
            image1.setTag(70);
            showingFirst = true;
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put both images into an `ImageSwitcher` and use the `Button` clicks to call its `showNext()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use if case in it like

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (i == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First Click", 1000).show();
            i++;
        } else if (i == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Second Click", 1000).show();
            i = 0;
        }
    }
```