# Switching Image of Imageview using onClickListener

Tags: android

I am making a music player app in which there is an image of the play button and once clicked it switch to pause.png and song start playing. Clicking again on the button will change the image to play.png and pause the sound. This pattern continues.

This question has been previously answered [first click change to new image and second click change to old image, android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622935/first-click-change-to-new-image-and-second-click-change-to-old-image-android)

But the checked answer doesn't work because boolean variable used to switch need to be declared final. And once declared final I cannot change the value of the variable.

Comment: you can declare the variable globally

Comment: than declare that Boolean before OnCreate().if you dont want to make final variable than you have to declare that variable in parent.

Comment: Thanks to Arpan Sharma and jigar savaliya declaring boolean globally worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boolean showingFirst = true;   //Declare globally

image1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(showingFirst){
            image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
            showingFirst = false;
        }else{
            image1.setImageResource(R.drawable.img2);
            showingFirst = true;
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. I will upvote the answer after getting 15 reputations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in this way using tag attribute of ImageView:

```
iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(iv.getTag().equals("playing")){
                iv.setImageResource(R.mipmap.play);
                iv.setTag("paused");
            } else {
                iv.setImageResource(R.mipmap.pause);
                iv.setTag("playing");
            }
        }
    });
```

And your ImageView declaration in xml file will be like below:

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/pause"
    android:tag="playing"
    android:id="@+id/iv"/>
```

Comment: This was a pretty interesting answer will keep in mind.

Comment: I am using the code provided by JaskaranSingh So I marked her as accepted. By the way thanks again.